# Getting data from a form loop and adding it to a pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a blade template that creates a form.  The form uses a foreach loop to iterate through a collection of questions and creates a form with these questions and a set of radio buttons.

```
@extends('main')

@section('content')
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <h4>New Check For {{$vehicle->reg}}.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <h5>{{$date}}</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <p><i>A fail on any check item will trigger an email to the office.</i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <p><i>Please add notes to explain faults in more detail, and to record any damage.</i></p>
    </div>

    </div>
    <hr>
    <form action="/vehicle_checks/{{$vehicle->id}}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <label for="mileage"><h4><strong>Mileage</strong> <i>(previous {{$previous_mileage}})</i></h4></label>
            <input class="ml-5 form-control-sm" style="border: solid 1px red" type="text" name="mileage" required="required">
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-1 col-7">
                <strong>Check</strong>
            </div>
        </div>


        <hr>
        @foreach($questions as $question)
            <div class="row mt-1">
                <div class="offset-1 col-7">
                    {{$question->question}}
                </div>

                <div class="col-2">
                    <label for="question{{$question->order}}">Pass</label>
                    <input type="radio" value="1" name="question{{$question->order}}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label for="question{{$question->order}}">Fail</label>
                    <input type="radio" value="0" name="question{{$question->order}}" checked>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        @endforeach
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-2 col-8">
                <label for="notes">Notes</label>
                <textarea style="width: 100%; border:solid 1px #1b1e21" rows=5 name="notes"></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>

            <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-6 col-2"></div>
                <a href="{{route('vehicle_checks.index', $vehicle->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Cancel</a>
                <button type="submit" class="ml-5 btn btn-sm btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
@stop
```

The problem I have is that in the controller I need to attach these questions and answers to a vehicle_check.
Currently this is what the controller looks like.

```
public function store(Vehicle $vehicle, Request $request)
    {
        $check =new VehicleCheck;
        $check->vehicle_id = $vehicle->id;
        $check->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $check->checked_on = Carbon::now();
        $check->mileage = $request->mileage;
        $check->notes = $request->notes;
        $check->save();

        //Code to attach question 1 to 14 and answer to the vehicle_check.

        Session::flash('success', 'Check saved!!');
        return redirect()->route('vehicle_checks.index', $vehicle);
    }
```

The relationships are as follows.
VehicleCheck.php

```
class VehicleCheck extends Model
{
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\VehicleQuestion')->withPivot('answer');
    }
}
```

VehicleQuestion.php

```
class VehicleQuestion extends Model
{
    public function check()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\VehicleCheck')->withPivot('answer');
    }
}
```

And here is the migration for the pivot.

```
class VehicleCheckVehicleQuestion extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('vehicle_check_vehicle_question', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('vehicle_check_id')->required();
            $table->unsignedInteger('vehicle_question_id')->required();
            $table->boolean('answer')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

How do I get to attach each question with its answer to the vehicle_check.

I've tried this

```
foreach($vehicle_check->questions as $questions)
{
    $vehicle_check->attach($question, ['answer' => (not sure how to access the answers in order from form);
}
```

Any help appreciated.
Paul.

Comment: Maybe include the question id with each answer in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may work, first you will need to serialize the form like this:

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
        <div class="row mt-1">
            <div class="offset-1 col-7">
                {{$question->question}}
            </div>

            <div class="col-2">
                <label for="">Pass</label>
                <input type="radio" value="1" name="answersPass[]">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <label for=""> Fail </label>
                <input type="radio" value="0" name="answersFail[]">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    @endforeach
```

Then in your controller you will be able to loop all the answers like this:

```
$answersPass = request('answersPass');
$answersFail = request('answersFail');
for(int i = 0 ; i < count($vehicle_check->questions) ; i++)
 {
   $vehicle_check->attach($questions[i], [answersPass[i], answersFail[i]]);
 }
```

I haven't tested the code above so tell me if works for you.

Comment: This seems like it may work but it causes all the pass radio buttons to be grouped so only one is selectable and the same for the fails.

Comment: I used your concept and swapped the radio buttons for check boxes.  All good then thanks.